# Loop and list all p-values

Tags: data, probability-or-statistics

I have the following mathematica code (see below). Is there a way to iterate this approach in such a way to get the p-value results of each test in a list? I would like to get say 1000 p-values for each test and graph their distributions. All at the $\alpha=0.01$ level of significance. Thank you!

```
DD[a_, b_, c_, μ_, ν_, σ_, τ_] = 
  MixtureDistribution[{a, b, c, a, b, 
    c}, {NormalDistribution[-μ, τ], 
    NormalDistribution[-ν, σ], 
    NormalDistribution[-μ - ν, σ + τ], 
    NormalDistribution[μ, τ], 
    NormalDistribution[ν, σ], 
    NormalDistribution[μ + ν, σ + τ]}];
data = RandomVariate[\[ScriptD] = 
   JohnsonDistribution["SU", 0, 1, 0, 1], 
  1000];  (*Target Distributions here*)
data1 = RandomVariate[f = DD[0.46, 0.435, 0.105, 0, 0, 0.671, 1.7], 
  1000]; (*SIGMA goes here*)
DistributionFitTest[data, f, {"TestDataTable", All}]
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here - you realize p-values under proper nulls will be uniformly distributed, yes? In any case, just create a list of test data lists (e.g., `RandomVariate[dist,{1000,1000}]`), map `DistributionFitTest` over that, extract the results and plot as desired. Look at documentation for `Map` for details on its use.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something here. The p-values are only distributed uniformly if the null hypothesis is true. This will not always be the case here.

Comment: That's essentially correct, (there are subtleties re: the converse), so if your goal is just to show the distributions, map as in prior comment.

Comment: Also, if you could provide the snippet of code to validate your approach, I would be most thankful.

Comment: Sure, gimmie a moment, I'll post a quick-n-dirty... NVM - Bob did so already, somewhat similar to what I cobbled up. Do note, the `SignificanceLevel` argument has no real meaning for this - It's used for the "reporting" and "diagnostic" functions of the test to determine rejection/acceptance, has no bearing on p-values generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DD[a_, b_, c_, μ_, ν_, σ_, τ_] = 
  MixtureDistribution[{a, b, c, a, b, 
    c}, {NormalDistribution[-μ, τ], 
    NormalDistribution[-ν, σ], 
    NormalDistribution[-μ - ν, σ + τ], 
    NormalDistribution[μ, τ], 
    NormalDistribution[ν, σ], 
    NormalDistribution[μ + ν, σ + τ]}];

tests = {AndersonDarlingTest, CramerVonMisesTest, 
   KolmogorovSmirnovTest, KuiperTest, PearsonChiSquareTest, 
   WatsonUSquareTest};

n = 100;(* change to your larger number, i.e., 1000 *)

pValues = Table[
    data = 
     RandomVariate[\[ScriptD] = JohnsonDistribution["SU", 0, 1, 0, 1],
       1000];(*Target Distributions here*)

    data1 = RandomVariate[
      f = DD[0.46, 0.435, 0.105, 0, 0, 0.671, 1.7], 
      1000];(*SIGMA goes here*)
    #[data, f, 
       SignificanceLevel -> 0.01] & /@ tests,
    {n}] // Transpose;

Partition[
  Histogram[#[[2]], PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] & /@
   Transpose[{tests, pValues}],
  2] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, +1, see my comment above re: `SignificanceLevel`